# V11 version mismatch

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
client.on("channelDelete", async channel => {
  let channelg = await db.fetch(`channel_${channel.guild.id}`);
    if (channelg == "on") {
  const logs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 'CHANNEL_DELETE' }).then(audit => audit.entries.first())
  const deleter = await channel.guild.members.fetch(logs.executor.id);
  if(deleter.id == channel.guild.owner.user.id) return;
  channel.clone(undefined, true, true, "channel delete system").then(async klon => {
    await klon.setParent(channel.parent);
    await klon.setPosition(channel.position);
        channel.guild.owner.send(`channel: **${channel.name}** channel it occurred again.`)
    console.log('correct')
  })
  }

})
```

allows you to create a channel back when it is deleted

how to make discord js V11 version compatible, V12 was prepared for release.

can you help? I hope everything is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace `guild.members.fetch()` with [`guild.fetchMember()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMember)

---

Also, the first argument of [`Channel.clone()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/typedef/GuildChannelCloneOptions) must be an `Object`.

Instead of `undefined`, just provide an empty `Object`, as all options in the first parameter are optional.

```js
channel.clone({}, true, true, "channel delete system")
```

Comment: (node:1828) Deprecation Warning: GuildChannel#clone: Clone channels using an opt
ions object instead of separate parameters.

I get the error

Comment: Check my edited answer for the `GuildChannel.clone()` problem.

Comment: (node:8888) Deprecation Warning: GuildChannel#clone: Clone channels using an opt
ions object instead of separate parameters.

I'm getting this error, I think we haven't found a solution :(

Comment: Uncaught Promise Error:  DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
ame: Could not interpret "{'0': 'd', '1': 'd'}" as string.

v11 actually I'm pretty sure